# Stack Overflow account - seek and recover request

Tags: support, user-accounts

I used Stack Overflow before, but not as a registered user. I rebuilt my PC in the meantime and I'd like to post again using may previous account. Is this possible?

Comment: belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: could you please fill in some extra details ?

Answer (score 1):

If you register with the site you'll have a permanent account you can use from any computer.

Once you've done that if you can then find one of your previous questions you can "flag" it for moderator attention. Explain that you want the accounts merging and they'll do it for you (after verifying that you are the owner of both).